# Accessing another list in the dataLabels.formatter function in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use another condition in the dataLabels.formatter function to determine whether to show a label or not and this another condition requires accessing a new list (indicated by "this.something" below) which will have exactly the same number of elements as the "data" list.

```
series: [
  {
    name: 'Value',
    data: [92.0, 92.0, 84.0],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.y > 90 && this.something == 1) { return this.y }
      }
    }
  }
],
```

How can I do this? I tried something like the following but it didn't work:

```
series: [
  {
    name: 'Value',
    data: [{
      y:92.0,
      something:0
    }, {
      y:92.0,
      something:1
    }, {
      y:84.0,
      something:0
    }],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        if (this.y > 90 && this.something == 1) { return this.y }
      }
    }
  }
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that I can use this.point.something to refer to the new field I added.

```
series: [
{
  name: 'Value',
  data: [{
    y:92.0,
    something:0
  }, {
    y:92.0,
    something:1
  }, {
    y:84.0,
    something:0
  }],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      if (this.y > 90 && this.point.something == 1) { return this.y }
    }
  }
}
```

],